# Creating client to consume websocket from custom server

Tags: c#, websocket

First of all, I am not a socket expert, but I have dabbled in Socket programming in some console applications.

What I need to do is to create a web client for a WebSocket (perhaps a `.ashx` or `.asmx` service).

What I need to do is to subscribe to a "resource" at the server, when this resource’s data is changed I should get a message returned that alerts me on this current change. I need to be able to post a header when I make this subscription, that contains a authorization key and other relevant data.

I have been looking all over for a solution but I can’t really find a example on how to consume a websocket in this fashion - Hopefully one of you guys can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I properly understand your needs you could try to check signalr library.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

Comment: Thanks - I actually forgot about this question and after some websocket studies it seems like it dosen't make sense to write the client in asp.net. The client was tested in a console app and after that written in a windows service.